# Please wait screen in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

The home page of my website and some other page also are taking some time to load, instead of making them load fast, I want some please wait screen or progress bar and mean while the required page would be loaded behind.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can try with Ajax [Update-Panel](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx)